# Error - single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: oracle, plsql, types

I've created a table type to pass multiple employee id's to my procedure. However, there is a requirement of, if nothing is passed to input parameter then all the employees should be retrieved.

Table type created -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMP_LIST IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

I wrote below query to check the null value but it failed with error - ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
SELECT COL_LIST FROM  EMP
WHERE EMP_ID IN (CASE WHEN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM table(EMP_LIST())) IS NULL 
                THEN (SELECT EMP_ID FROM EMP) 
                ELSE (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM table(EMP_LIST())) END)
```

CASE cannot return multiple values. Could someone please suggest an alternative or any other solution to handle such scenario?

Thank You.

Comment: Maybe `emp_list` should be named `number_list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this type you can write:

```
with t as (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE cv FROM table(EMP_LIST()))
SELECT COL_LIST FROM EMP
  where emp_id in (select cv from t) 
     or (select count(1) from t) = 0
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0c84aea11bc9d9f40ad40ca2396d8630)</sup>**

Edit - explanation:

```
with t as (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE cv FROM table(EMP_LIST()))
```

This part is called CTE (common table expression). It is typically used when subquery is needed in main query twice or more, like here.

```
  where emp_id in (select cv from t)
```

like in your attempt (first use of CTE)

```
     or (select count(1) from t) = 0
```

second use of CTE. `WHERE` condition together allows us to see rows which are in list provided in CTE **or all rows** if count of provided numbers is zero.

You can do that without CTE, but this way you had to define list twice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is working amazingly! Could you please explain how does this work (select count(1) from t) = 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your predicate

```
((select count(0) from table(emp_list()))=0 and emp_id IN (
                SELECT
                    emp_id
                FROM
                    emp
            )
            )
 or emp_id in (
                SELECT
                    column_value
                FROM
                    TABLE ( emp_list() )
            )
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this but it is giving me an error - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"